# What is the best/most secure way to pass an id from a page to another?

Tags: php, session, variables, post, get

I am working on a PHP/MySQL messaging application in which a user can see a conversation and reply to it. On the view page of the message I have a reply field. To save the reply I need to know the ID of the message which is being replied to. I have been trying to pass this ID in a way, which is both secure and reliable. A simple hidden field with a POST won't do it, since the user can tamper the data and modify which message he is answering. Creating a session variable with the id of the message on the view page provides the security but causes a highly undesirable side-effect: if the user views another message after opening the one he is replying to, the response will be posted to the other message.

Any one got any alternatives ?

Comment: If you don't have server-side permissions to check, how do you exactly determine whether the user can answer?

Comment: I do, but nothing prevents a person to go to a message where he can reply, send a reply and tamper the id of the message being answered to.

Comment: Server-side permissions would prevent him...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can encrypt the id with the [mcrypt](http://php.net/mcrypt) library and pass the encrypted form in the url. If your userbase has the collective IQ of a zucchini, you could probably get away with simple obfuscating as Hex or base64. But otherwise, mcrypt->base64 will be more than enough

Answer (score 0):

Use 2 kind of ID, like:  ?id=45sdf6g78g9s7987sd9f87&id_hash=65d4f98s7gsdg54g98dg